# Is there way to populate fields from SubDocuments?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following model where I'm using SubDocuments:

```
const SubCategory = new Schema({
   label: { type: String}    
});

const Category = new Schema({
    label: { type: String},
    subcategories: [SubCategory]
});
```

Also I have a model where I'd like to save subcategory

```
const Article = new Schema({
   title: { type: String }
   subcategory: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'SubCategory'}
},
```

Could you help me how I should populate `subcategory` for `Article` model?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: To populate a document the referenced document needs to be in its own collection.

> Population is the process of automatically replacing the specified paths in the document with document(s) from other collection(s). -- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

So in the example above, `SubCategory` would need to be a model/collection on its own that is referenced from both the `Category` collection and the `Article` collection.